# Surjectivity of the second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections, submanifold

Let $M^m \subseteq N^n$ be a submanifold, with $(N, g)$ a Riemannian manifold and the Levi-civita connection denoted by $\nabla$. Consider the second fundamental form generalized to arbitrary codimension

$$B: TM \times TM \to N(M)$$
$$v,w \in TM, \qquad B(v,w) = (\nabla_v w)^{\perp}$$

can anything be said about the surjectivity of this operator based on $m$, $n$, and $g$? I would think
$$
m \geq n - m
$$
is a necessary condition, otherwise something like a curved line in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Similarly, if the connection is trivial (maybe flat is the right word?), then the map is probably not surjective.

Comment: If $M$ is a totally geodesic submanifold, then $B=0$, so it really depends on the geometry. There are all sorts of interesting surfaces ($m=2$) in dimension $5$ (whether real or complex) where the second fundamental form has rank $\le 2$, but generically one expects $B$ to be surjective. So your condition is definitely *not* necessary.

Comment: Very interesting! Do you have a reference for surjectivity being generic? Thanks for your comment

Comment: I wrote a paper years ago called "The Osculatory Behavior of Surfaces in $\Bbb P^5$." There's a false theorem in there, but the basic things are all correct. However, for your purposes, probably section 1 more than suffices. The intuition is that if $f(u,v)$ is a local parametrization, you expect the derivatives $f_u,f_v,f_{uu},f_{uv},f_{vv}$ to be linearly independent generically. You should also look at the 1979 paper by Griffiths & Harris, "Algebraic Geometry and Local Differential Geometry."